# Call to undefined method Cart::getDeposit() in

Tags: php, prestashop

I got this error in my prestashop when I installed a new module named `myownreservations`.

Can anyone help? I'm not the best to this.
Thanks a lot.

> [18-Feb-2016 17:38:34 Europe/Copenhagen] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Cart::getDeposit() in /home/wpshopfr/public_html/xxxxxx.dk/modules/myownreservations/controllers/hooks.php on line 259

And this is the code:

```
if ($cart->getDeposit()>0 && Configuration::get('MYOWNRES_DEPOSIT_SHOW')!=1 ) {
    $depositMsg = Configuration::get('MYOWNRES_MSG_DEPOSIT', $cookie->id_lang);
    self::forceTranslation('blockcart', '', 'Wrapping', $depositMsg);
    self::forceTranslation('', 'shopping-cart', 'Total gift-wrapping:', $depositMsg.':');
    self::forceTranslation('', 'shopping-cart', 'Total gift-wrapping (tax incl.):', $depositMsg.':');
    self::forceTranslation('', 'shopping-cart', 'Total gift-wrapping', $depositMsg);
    self::forceTranslation('', 'order-payment', 'Total gift-wrapping:', $depositMsg.':');
    self::forceTranslation('', 'order-payment', 'Total gift-wrapping (tax incl.):', $depositMsg.':');
    self::forceTranslation('', 'order-payment', 'Total gift-wrapping', $depositMsg);
}
```

Comment: Did you include the PHP file that has the Cart class in it?

Comment: by default `Cart` class has no `getDeposit` method in Presta, that is what you see in error message. Check this new module files, maybe there is file to override Cart class, that you need to put in /override folder etc.